# module 'matplotlib' has no attribute 'imshow'

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I am trying to display data as an image using matplotlib, but I received this error:
*AttributeError module 'matplotlib' has no attribute 'imshow'*

Here is an example code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as plt 

im = np.arange(10)
im = im[np.newaxis, :]
im = np.repeat(im, 10, axis=0)
plt.imshow(im, cmap='gray')
```

using :
python : 3.7.9
matplotlib: 3.3.4

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The import should be:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

Comment: I have tried this and it works, thanks!

Comment: For me, I subconsciously type 'imgshow' instead of 'imshow' and then I go down this rabbit hole.